# App not compatible - Amazon App Store

Tags: amazon-appstore

I tried to publish an app to the amazon app store.
It contains 100% the same AndroidManifest as the app I published in the google play store. Code wise is i 99% the same, just removed the premium features and the IAP billing.

When I upload the apk file it shows 0+ devices as compatible:

[image: app store compatible devices]

when I go through the compatible devices list, I just see very old devices running Marshmallow. There are no devices in the list running Oreo.
I thought it would suffice to enable "All other Android devices".

[image: app store compatible devices]

But I got a message from amazon:

> Your app submission does not meet one or more of our acceptance criteria for some or all targeted devices. Failure reason(s) are listed below:
>   Steps to Reproduce: Install and launch the app: Actual Result:
>   Unable to download the app into any of the compatible devices mentioned hence unable to check in-app. Expected Result: App should work fine on launch of the app.

What I'm doing wrong?
My min api is 25, target api 26.

Comment: 6 years later still same problem. They don't seem to have any newer devices. My min sdk is 26. It's already 5 years old.

Answer (score 0):

In the Device Support dialog (your 2nd screenshot above), notice there's a '?' icon next to each incompatible device. Hover over the icon and it should show the exact reason why your app is incompatible for that device based on Android manifest filtering.